# Spatial database for Android with Sqlite

Tags: android, augmented-reality, spatial, spatial-index

This question has been asked a lot of times but I did not find a relevant solution for my requirement.

I want to build a simple Augmented reality App on Android which uses Spatial data (R-Tree) to store the geographic data. I found this solution [Spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android) which seems great, but I had few problems with their tools and it looks quite complex for my app. 
Another trick is to use SQLite with SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE enabled, which requires me to build my own SQlite libraries.

All I need is to store Spatial data compatible to R-Tree algorithm (I have small set of data covering buildings within a university campus) in the phone and then query it according to the current location.

I am looking for some direction to achieve this, mostly on the storage part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am working on something similar.

Comment: same problem as me, Do you have the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the usefulness of the R-Tree is evident with large datasets. Have you tested performance just using standard SQL w/ standard indexes?  Just a snippet from the SQLite page:

```
    SELECT id FROM campus WHERE x>=-81.08 AND x<=-80.58 AND y>=35.00 AND y<=35.44
```

I understand you may not want the maintenance burden of compiling SQLite yourself.

http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html

What about switching to JavaScript?

https://github.com/imbcmdth/RTree/tree/master/examples